# How to store credit card number in Merchant Warehouse Data Vault?

Tags: php, transactions, credit-card

I am planning to integrate merchant ware payment gateway for credit card transaction in my current project. For that I need to save the credit card number in merchant ware vault not to a database. I have the API files, but none of the files explains how can we store credit card number to vault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the way to store credit card number in Merchantware vault,
See the link for more details [Merchantware Credit Card Payment Transaction](https://staging.merchantware.net/Merchantware/doc40/idtechenh/overview_enumtransactiontype.aspx)